# Python - Way to view code that's being executed in real time?

Tags: python, linux

I want to see what commands my python script is executing as it runs in real time (for the purpose of presentation.) I am limited to using a linux terminal here.

I have tried ipython's demo mode, using the 'trace.getsource()' method, and using 'sys.setprofile()'. ipython's demo mode requires you to insert # comments into the source code, which isn't ideal.

Does anyone know if what I am describing is possible to do in a linux terminal?

Comment: I'm not aware of any solutions to easily accomplish what you want. But it should be easy to write a simple script or program that will take your source files and double them in size, interleaving appropriate # comment lines between each source line, where each comment contains the text of the source code on the line below it.

Comment: step through in pdb? or is that not real time? ... why are you limited to linux terminal(you mean console?)?